# How to create/read calendars and events Azure Activity Directory [Microsoft.Graph]

Tags: c#, azure, active-directory, office365, microsoft-graph-api

We want to interact with Office 365 Calendar, in this moment we are calling Microsoft Graph but we get a 401 (Unauthorized).

We are using the Microsoft.Graph library and the typical get users (graphServiceClient.Users.Request().GetAsync()) does work but creating a Calendar or Event doesn't work. (nor GraphServiceClient.Me.[...].Request().GetAsync() works).

We are trying this call manually, we didn't find a way to do through the library.

[image: call to Microsoft Graph Calendar]

And this is how we get the token (We use client authentication not user authentication).

[image: How we get the token]

Desperately we gave all the permission to the app, but we are still getting 401

[image]

The token analyzed with jwt.io:

```
{
      "aud": "https://graph.microsoft.com",
      "iss": "https://sts.windows.net/11111111-24c0-480b-8ae3-a3ac34592a1a/",
      "iat": 1541581025,
      "nbf": 1541581025,
      "exp": 1541584925,
      "aio": "11111111111/AAAAA+115sO7D/yAwA=",
      "app_displayname": "CalendarCrawler",
      "appid": "11111111-efc2-4b9d-ae48-a04977183bd1",
      "appidacr": "1",
      "e_exp": 262800,
      "idp": "https://sts.windows.net/11111111-24c0-480b-8ae3-a3ac34592a1a/",
      "oid": "11111111-15f2-479c-9485-7cb9b5cce691",
      "roles": [
        "Chat.UpdatePolicyViolation.All",
        "Calls.JoinGroupCall.All",
        "EduRoster.Read.All",
        "OnlineMeetings.Read.All",
        "Mail.ReadWrite",
        "OnlineMeetings.ReadWrite.All",
        "Device.ReadWrite.All",
        "User.ReadWrite.All",
        "Domain.ReadWrite.All",
        "Application.ReadWrite.OwnedBy",
        "SecurityEvents.Read.All",
        "Calendars.Read",
        "EduAssignments.ReadWrite.All",
        "People.Read.All",
        "Application.ReadWrite.All",
        "Calls.InitiateGroupCall.All",
        "Group.Read.All",
        "Directory.ReadWrite.All",
        "EduAssignments.ReadWriteBasic.All",
        "MailboxSettings.Read",
        "EduAdministration.Read.All",
        "Calls.JoinGroupCallAsGuest.All",
        "Sites.Read.All",
        "Sites.ReadWrite.All",
        "Contacts.ReadWrite",
        "Group.ReadWrite.All",
        "Sites.Manage.All",
        "SecurityEvents.ReadWrite.All",
        "Notes.Read.All",
        "User.Invite.All",
        "EduRoster.ReadWrite.All",
        "Files.ReadWrite.All",
        "Directory.Read.All",
        "User.Read.All",
        "EduAssignments.ReadBasic.All",
        "EduRoster.ReadBasic.All",
        "Files.Read.All",
        "Mail.Read",
        "Chat.Read.All",
        "ChannelMessage.Read.All",
        "EduAssignments.Read.All",
        "Calendars.ReadWrite",
        "identityriskyuser.read.all",
        "EduAdministration.ReadWrite.All",
        "Mail.Send",
        "ChannelMessage.UpdatePolicyViolation.All",
        "MailboxSettings.ReadWrite",
        "Contacts.Read",
        "IdentityRiskEvent.Read.All",
        "AuditLog.Read.All",
        "Member.Read.Hidden",
        "Calls.AccessMedia.All",
        "Sites.FullControl.All",
        "Reports.Read.All",
        "Calls.Initiate.All",
        "Notes.ReadWrite.All"
      ],
      "sub": "11111111-15f2-479c-9485-7cb9b5cce691",
      "tid": "11111111-24c0-480b-8ae3-a3ac34592a1a",
      "uti": "CFOL_8eguUS2aGh5-jgOAA",
      "ver": "1.0",
      "xms_tcdt": 1541410090
    }
```

Any suggestion?

Thanks in advance

[EDIT]
We have done another question more clear, please follow [How to use Microsoft.Graph with client authorization and not get a 401](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53193401/how-to-use-microsoft-graph-with-client-authorization-and-not-get-a-401)

Comment: Did you hit the "Grant Permissions" button (visible in your screenshot as well) after adding those application permissions? I ask this because all of the permissions you selected say requires Admin consent, so "Grant Permissions" will be required.

Comment: Yes, I did it. I added the Office 365 permissions too but nothing.

Comment: ok.. and since you're using application credentials, you don't really have a user context, so I hope your query to read isn't something that works with /me path for example.. can you include the code/query where you try to read from the calendar and create events in calendar?

Comment: For the moment we are trying calling the API manually  -> https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/USERID/calendars and we get a 401. The token is created with authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(config.Scope, new ClientCredential (config.ClientId, config.ClientSecret));

Answer (score 0):

I would try the call from [Graph Explorer in Developer portal](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) to check if the issue is AD Permission.  If you are successful then issue is not with AD Permission but token creation.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D7ssy.png)

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/D7ssy.png]

More information https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_post_events

Comment: With my Office365 account I can see my events etc. Is there a way to simulate the application/active directory login? (I have the same mail account for different activity directories)

Comment: Never user graph with a application/service account but when you think about it. You need a mailbox to get a calendar or calendar events. AAD application do not have mailboxes. That might be your issue here.  Food for thought.

Answer (score 0):

Based on related API such as [Post events](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_post_events) API, we could know that `Calendars.ReadWrite` permission is required. But It also need to requires Admin consent, so please don't forget to  "Grant Permissions". If you are using admin account then you could do that.

[image]

> We are trying this call manually, we didn't find a way to do through the library.

The following code is the demo how to get/create calendars and create event through the library.

> **Note**: The user must be an **office365 account**, or will get `ResourceNotFound` exception.

```
string graphResourceId = "https://graph.microsoft.com/";
string authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}";
string tenantId = "tenantId";
var accessToken = authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(graphResourceId, new ClientCredential(clientId,secret)).Result.AccessToken;
AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
var graphserviceClient = new GraphServiceClient(
                new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(
                    requestMessage =>
                    {
                        requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", accessToken);

                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    }));

//get calendars
var calendars = graphserviceClient.Users["userObjectId"].Calendars.Request().GetAsync().Result
//new calendar
var calendar = graphserviceClient.Users["userObjectId"].Calendars.Request().AddAsync(
            new Calendar {
               Name = "name"
            }).Result

//new event
var cal = graphserviceClient.Users["userObjectId"].Events.Request().AddAsync(
            new Event {
                Subject = "test",
                Start = new DateTimeTimeZone {DateTime = "2018-11-07T00:56:52.584Z",TimeZone = "UTC" },
                End = new DateTimeTimeZone { DateTime = "2018-11-07T01:56:52.584Z", TimeZone = "UTC" }

            }).Result;
```

Comment: We don't use user authentication, we are using application credentials and with this code we still get "Unauthorized"

Comment: My demo code is also using the application permission. But I don't have office365 account, I got ResourceNotFound exception, not Unauthorized exception. According to the [API document](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_post_events), it mentioned that it supports application permission. Have you tried to use https://jwt.io to decode the access token to check the scope?

Comment: Is your account an admin account?

Comment: I added the token analysis to the main post. My user account is admin account in the Azure AD but in the application we aren't using it but the application itself.