# How to use Microsoft.Graph with client authorization and not get a 401

Tags: azure, outlook, azure-active-directory, office365, microsoft-graph-api

We have

- created Azure Active Directory
- created a new Application
- registered the new Application in Azure AD
- given ALL the permissions to the API
- granted admin permissions

Now we login with this app credentials

We get authorization:

```
GET /1111111-aaaa-4fd3-bf32-9bfc460f67b1/oauth2/v2.0/authorize HTTP/1.1
Host: login.microsoftonline.com
cache-control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 111111-aaaa-4696-9828-9110670706c5
```

We get the token:

```
POST /11111111-aaaa-4fd3-bf32-9bfc460f67b1/oauth2/v2.0/token HTTP/1.1
Host: login.microsoftonline.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
cache-control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 11111111-aaaa-47e4-b2fb-6b94cd02312a
client_id=11111111-aaaa-482e-ab17-86e4c2c6240c
scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2F.default
client_secret=aaaaaaaaaaaDJk6jBJ%2FuBRJM6AFxyFIDMKn867hmvU%3D
grant_type=client_credentials
```

The token analyzed with jwt.io:

```
{
  "aud": "https://graph.microsoft.com",
  "iss": "https://sts.windows.net/1111111-ccc6-4fd3-bf32-9bfc460f67b1/",
  "iat": 1541603660,
  "nbf": 1541603660,
  "exp": 1541607560,
  "aio": "42RgYFB+/Gyh8uF3yl+uKU7km//kFwA=",
  "app_displayname": "ToDoListService",
  "appid": "1111111-4e99-482e-ab17-86e4c2c6240c",
  "appidacr": "1",
  "idp": "https://sts.windows.net/1111111-ccc6-4fd3-bf32-9bfc460f67b1/",
  "oid": "1111111-98fb-4a47-af7f-d3800dde2f7b",
  "roles": [
    "Chat.UpdatePolicyViolation.All",
    "Calls.JoinGroupCall.All",
    "EduRoster.Read.All",
    "OnlineMeetings.Read.All",
    "Mail.ReadWrite",
    "OnlineMeetings.ReadWrite.All",
    "Device.ReadWrite.All",
    "User.ReadWrite.All",
    "Domain.ReadWrite.All",
    "Application.ReadWrite.OwnedBy",
    "SecurityEvents.Read.All",
    "Calendars.Read",
    "EduAssignments.ReadWrite.All",
    "People.Read.All",
    "Application.ReadWrite.All",
    "Calls.InitiateGroupCall.All",
    "Group.Read.All",
    "Directory.ReadWrite.All",
    "EduAssignments.ReadWriteBasic.All",
    "MailboxSettings.Read",
    "EduAdministration.Read.All",
    "Calls.JoinGroupCallAsGuest.All",
    "Sites.Read.All",
    "Sites.ReadWrite.All",
    "Contacts.ReadWrite",
    "Group.ReadWrite.All",
    "Sites.Manage.All",
    "SecurityEvents.ReadWrite.All",
    "Notes.Read.All",
    "User.Invite.All",
    "EduRoster.ReadWrite.All",
    "Files.ReadWrite.All",
    "Directory.Read.All",
    "User.Read.All",
    "EduAssignments.ReadBasic.All",
    "EduRoster.ReadBasic.All",
    "Files.Read.All",
    "Mail.Read",
    "Chat.Read.All",
    "ChannelMessage.Read.All",
    "EduAssignments.Read.All",
    "Calendars.ReadWrite",
    "identityriskyuser.read.all",
    "EduAdministration.ReadWrite.All",
    "Mail.Send",
    "ChannelMessage.UpdatePolicyViolation.All",
    "MailboxSettings.ReadWrite",
    "Contacts.Read",
    "IdentityRiskEvent.Read.All",
    "AuditLog.Read.All",
    "Member.Read.Hidden",
    "Calls.AccessMedia.All",
    "Sites.FullControl.All",
    "Reports.Read.All",
    "Calls.Initiate.All",
    "Notes.ReadWrite.All"
  ],
  "sub": "1111111-98fb-4a47-af7f-d3800dde2f7b",
  "tid": "1111111-ccc6-4fd3-bf32-9bfc460f67b1",
  "uti": "hxPwbjRRm0y6SI8hxuckAA",
  "ver": "1.0",
  "xms_tcdt": 1541414851
}
```

You can see that we get all the necesary permissions.

And this petition works:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/Users/
```

or

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/Users/
```

but not this one:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/Users/<user-id>/Calendars
```

nor this one:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/<user-id>/sendMail
```

they both return 401:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "UnknownError",
    "message": "",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "019ddc83-6528-4f19-95cc-8b99ea53a046",
      "date": "2018-11-07T16:03:55"
    }
  }
}
```

I think that we had got all the necessary permission, configuration... etc... so why isn't it working? :'(

[UPDATE]

detailed call to get calendars

```
GET /v1.0/Users/<user-id>/Calendars HTTP/1.1
cache-control: no-cache
Postman-Token: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Authorization: Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.3.0
Accept: */*
Host: graph.microsoft.com
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: close
```

Response

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Cache-Control: private
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/json
request-id: 11111111-aaaa-aaaa-a115-e09bb6f09917
client-request-id: 11111111-aaaa-aaaa-a115-e09bb6f09917
x-ms-ags-diagnostic: {"ServerInfo":{"DataCenter":"North Europe","Slice":"SliceC","Ring":"3","ScaleUnit":"001","Host":"AGSFE_IN_34","ADSiteName":"NEU"}}
Duration: 377.0084
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
Date: Thu, 08 Nov 2018 09:16:03 GMT
Connection: close

c6
{
  "error": {
    "code": "UnknownError",
    "message": "",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "2bb9a7c1-f8a3-4c1f-a115-e09bb6f09917",
      "date": "2018-11-08T09:16:04"
    }
  }
}
0
```

Comment: did you find the reason for failure ? Let us know

Answer (score 3):

let me start by first of all noticing that you have posted a client secret on a public forum :) And one that has luxurious permission on your tenant. I hope you have changed the client secret by now.

But to get back to your question - I will have to ask a bit more in detail to get a better understanding of what your actual results were:

1. According to your JWT printout you are getting a V1 token but using the **client credential** flow (the field "ver" is set to 1.0). The Microsoft Documentation here [Get access without a user](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_v2_service) explicitly states that you should use a V2 Token to access Microsoft Graph in this scenario. So the first question is: Did you create your Azure App using the V2 Portal: https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/ ? If not then this may be the issue.
2. A more common issue when manually testing - Have you made sure that the token had not expired from the time you got it from the /token endpoint up to the time you tested your API call?
3. If none of the above - please post your request to the https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/Users//Calendars endpoint in detail, the devil may be in the details

Comment: 1. We have used https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/ portal and the azure AD App Registration (preview) too but we still get token ver 1.0. We don't really undertand the connection between AD and app registration portal. They don't reference each other specifically.
2. we are sure
3. I have updated the main post

Comment: For Exchange Online Calls like /Calendar that you are using - please note that here you may need Exchange Online Permissions in addition to the Graph API permission (see [link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/exchangedev/2015/01/21/building-daemon-or-service-apps-with-office-365-mail-calendar-and-contacts-apis-oauth2-client-credential-flow/). So go to your app, add API Access also to Office 365 Exchange Online -> **Read calendars in all mailboxes** then consent again and try again.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, is it necessary for this to work to have an office365 license?
I'm logging against endpoint v2.0 (gives me a v1.0 token btw), trying to retrieve Calendars from personal Microsoft accounts and still getting a 401.

Comment: Did you find the answer atlast ?

Comment: Just one tip for those who want to force the issuance of v2 tokens: you can set the value "accessTokenAcceptedVersion": 2 in the App Manifest in Azure AD (where the App was registered) so that the endpoint issuing access tokens is constrained to do it or refuse the request. The default for that attribute if not defined is "1" so because of this you will receive a v1 token by default.